# Content REST view does not work because of moderation states

Tags: nodes, 8, workbench

I've created a simple view using the `REST export` to export all published content in JSON format, but I get this error:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException:
    Route "entity.moderation_state.canonical" does not exist.
    in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName()
    (line 191 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php).

Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->getRoute('entity.moderation_state.canonical') (Line: 285)
Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->generateFromRoute('entity.moderation_state.canonical', Array, Array, 1) (Line: 110)
Drupal\Core\Render\MetadataBubblingUrlGenerator->generateFromRoute('entity.moderation_state.canonical', Array, Array, ) (Line: 754)
Drupal\Core\Url->toString() (Line: 291)
```

Moderation states have indeed been added, but I have no idea why that's throwing this kind of error...

Answer (score 0):

The route is not in core. Probably it is in a contrib or custom module. You have to search for a *.routing.yml file, where it is defined and then look for an error in the yml file and then clear the cache.

You can get a complete list of all routes with drupal console:

```
drupal route:debug
```